# VueJs. How to close pre-loader after data from server have been loaded

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I use VueX in my VueJs app and I need to close pre-loader after I got an answer from server for 4 my get requests. I try to use callback function to change pre-loader state but it changes after requests STARTs, but I need to change pre-loader state after all requests SUCCESS. Below is my code:

Index.vue

```
<template>
 <div class="index">
  <div class="content-is-loading"
     v-if="appIsLoading"></div>
  <div v-else class="index__wrapper">
   <navbarInner></navbarInner>
   <div class="index__content">
    <sidebar></sidebar>
    <router-view></router-view>
   </div>
   <foo></foo>
  </div>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
import NavbarInner from './NavbarInner'
import Sidebar from './Sidebar'
import Foo from './../Foo'
import Shows from './Shows/Shows'
import Dashboard from './Dashboard'
import { API_URL } from '../../../config/constants'
import { mapState } from 'vuex'
export default {
 name: 'index',
 data () {
  return {
   appIsLoading: true,
   bandName: ''
  }
 },
components: {
 NavbarInner,
 Sidebar,
 Foo,
 Shows,
 Dashboard
},
created () {

 function loadData (context, callback) {
  // Loading bands for the user
  context.$store.dispatch('getBands')

  // Loading contacts for the user
  context.$store.dispatch('getContacts')

  // Loading merch for the user
  context.$store.dispatch('getInventory')

  // Loading tours for the active band
  context.$store.dispatch('getToursList')

  callback(context)
 }

 loadData(this, function (context) {
   context.appIsLoading = false
  })
 }
}
```

Below I add code of one of the request:
api/tour.js

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { API_URL } from '../../config/constants'

export default {

 getToursList () {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   let bandId = window.localStorage.getItem('active_band_id')
   let token = window.localStorage.getItem('token')
   axios.get(API_URL + '/api/bands/' + bandId + '/tours/', {
     headers: {'x-access-token': token}
   })
    .then((result) => {
      return resolve(result.data)
    })
    .catch(err => reject(err))
  })
 },

 getInventory () {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   let token = window.localStorage.getItem('token')
    axios.get(API_URL + '/api/merch/listProductForUser/1000/0', {
     headers: {'x-access-token': token}
   })
    .then((response) => {
      let items = response.data
      return resolve(items)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      return reject(err)
    })
   })
  },

 getContacts () {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   let token = window.localStorage.getItem('token')
    axios.get(API_URL + '/api/contact/get_contacts_for_user/1000/0', {
     headers: {'x-access-token': token}
   })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data)
      let contacts = response.data
      return resolve(contacts)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      return reject(err)
    })
  })
 },

 getBands () {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   let token = window.localStorage.getItem('token')
    axios.get(API_URL + '/api/band/getBandsForUser/1000/0', {
     headers: {'x-access-token': token}
   })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data)
      let bands = response.data
      return resolve(bands)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      return reject(err)
    })
  })
 }
}
```

Vuex/tour.js

```
import api from '../../api/onload'
import * as types from '../mutation-types'
const state = {
 tours: [],
 contacts: [],
 bands: [],
 merch: [],
 success: false,
 loading: false
}

const actions = {
 getToursList ({commit}) {
  api.getToursList()
   .then((tours) => {
    commit(types.RECEIVE_TOURS, tours)
   }).catch((err) => {
    console.error('Error receiving tours: ', err)
    commit(types.RECEIVE_TOURS_ERROR)
  })
},

getInventory ({commit}) {
 api.getInventory()
  .then((items) => {
    commit(types.RECEIVE_INVENTORY, items)
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error('Error receiving inventory: ', err)
    commit(types.RECEIVE_INVENTORY_ERROR)
  })
},

getBands ({commit}) {
 api.getBands()
  .then((bands) => {
    commit(types.RECEIVE_BANDS, bands)
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error('Error receiving bands: ', err)
    commit(types.RECEIVE_BANDS_ERROR)
  })
},

getContacts ({commit}) {
 api.getContacts()
  .then((contacts) => {
    commit(types.RECEIVE_CONTACTS, contacts)
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error('Error receiving bands: ', err)
    commit(types.RECEIVE_CONTACTS_ERROR)
  })
 }
}

const mutations = {
 [types.RECEIVE_TOURS] (state, tours) {
  state.tours = tours
},

[types.RECEIVE_INVENTORY] (state, items) {
 state.items = items
},

[types.RECEIVE_BANDS] (state, bands) {
 state.bands = bands
},

[types.RECEIVE_CONTACTS] (state, contacts) {
  state.contacts = contacts
  console.log(state.contacts)
 }
}

export default {
 state, mutations, actions
}
```

How should I change the code?

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted doesn't actually wait on the response from any of the actions you are calling.

You could also move everything to a method and refactor.

Finally I've assumed your actions return a Promise i.e.

```
created () {
  this.getAll()
},

methods: {

  getAll () {

    Promise.all([
        this.$store.dispatch('getBands'),
        this.$store.dispatch('getContacts'),
        this.$store.dispatch('getInventory'),
        this.$store.dispatch('getToursList'),
    ])
    .then(responseArray => {
        this.appIsLoading = false
    })
    .catch(error => { console.error(error) })
```

**EDIT**

To get your actions to resolve as you need them (when the mutations have fired and your store is updated) you need to wrap them in a Promise:

**Vuex/tour.js** (actions object)

```
getToursList: ({ commit }) =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        api.getToursList()
            .then((tours) => {
                commit(types.RECEIVE_TOURS, tours)
                resolve()
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.error('Error receiving tours: ', err)
                commit(types.RECEIVE_TOURS_ERROR)
                reject()
            })

    })
```

Comment: that probably means your actions aren't returning Promises or that they are failing. Have you tried adding a catch - updated answer to show this

Comment: The thing is that I've checked all 4 request and they returns data. Also if `this.appIsLoading` getting to be `false` means there is no error and of course I've checked your idea with error. 
I start thinking that I need to make something similar with the code in `api/tour.js` module and change pre-loader state also in vuex

Comment: sorry I didn't fully understand your last comment - do you mean `this.appIsLoading = false` is being called?

Comment: Correct. `this.appIsLoading = false` is being called.

Comment: well that's great - so the Promise.all is resolving. What then do you need to happen? This should therefore be revealing the div with a class of `index__wrapper` which I thought was what you were after, is this not the case? If not what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The thing is that this div reveals when the request SENT but I need it to reveal when data have been LOADED and all reactive elements updated.

Comment: I just noticed that your actions aren't Promises so this is likely the issue, you need to wrap these as they're what we are calling, I'll update above to reflect this.

Comment: Did that sort it?